# what is wrong with this callback (deal with NaN)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app which is dealing with lots of calculations.

Instead of changing the corresponding value(s) to zero it just raises `NaN`.

```
before_save :change_nan_to_zero
def change_nan_to_zero
  self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
    if value == Float::NAN
      value = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Or, maybe (there always is) there is a better way to deal with NaN (particularly change it everywhere to `0`). Thx!

## SOLVED

Ok, got it. The issue was that actually nothing was saved as `NaN`, but it was the calculations (results of which were not saved into db) that issued `NaN`. So I've ended up with helper for views (containing calculations results):

```
  def zero_or_value(value)
    if value.is_a?(Float)
        value.nan? ? 0 : value
    else
      value
    end     
  end
```

Thanks everyone for help! I am really appreciated! @Marek, I am sure your answer is right (I've used it for my solution partially, for sure I'll upvote for help, guys!)

Comment: Try to write as `value.class==Float::NAN`

Answer (score 4):

Your solution doesn't work, because you only set local variable `value` to `0`. Also, to check if float is nan, you should use `nan?` method (comparison to Float::NAN won't work). What you should do is:

```
if value.is_a?(Float) && value.nan?
  write_attribute(key, 0)
end
```

or, in shorter version:

```
write_attribute(key, 0) if value.nan?
```

Comment: the answer really looks good and right, but somehow I am getting PRIMARY KEY must be unique error

Comment: @andreydeineko `attributes` contain `id` and you can't set `id` it's `PRIMARY KEY`!

Comment: Though it's strange that `id` is being set. It shouldn't pas `if` condition.

Comment: @MarekLipka `attributes` return all column in `table` and `id` too

Comment: @Зелёный of course, but `id != Float::NAN`, so it shouldn't be set I guess.

Comment: @andreydeineko could you paste full backtrace in the question?

Comment: @andreydeineko I edited my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: @MarekLipka done. It can be important - I need this functionality for both save and update actions. Thanks a bunch for helping!!

Comment: @MarekLipka no errors are being thrown now, but still I am getting -$NaN instead of zeroes..

Comment: @andreydeineko ok so how do you set these values?

Comment: I'm using the lastly updated answer. I've debugged with raise, and it is not gettin into if statement

Comment: @andreydeineko so try to debug before `if`. You could use `pry` for debugging, it's quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` variable contains a copy of the original one: changing it will have no effect. Instead, use the key to refer to the original number:

```
before_save :change_nan_to_zero
def change_nan_to_zero
  self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
    if value == Float::NAN
      self.attributes[key] = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The real reason it doesn't work isn't that it's a copy of original value, but because `value = 0` is local variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually setting the database attribute, just a local variable.  I think you actually want something like this:

```
before_save :change_nan_to_zero
def change_nan_to_zero
  self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
    if value == Float::NAN
      write_attribute(key, 0)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: UPDATE query called for every `nan` - I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: Good point, your `write_attribute` would be better.  Still early here :)